# Doing HTTP request in Scala

Tags: http, scala, scalaz

I am trying to issue a simple POST request to a webservice which returns some XML in Scala.

It seems that [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) is the standard library used for this task, but I cannot find documentation for it. The main site, which I link above, explains at length what is a promise and how to do asynchronous programming, but does not actually document the API. There is a [periodic table](http://www.flotsam.nl/dispatch-periodic-table.html) - which looks a bit scary - but it only seems useful to people who already know what to do and only need a reminder for the cryptic syntax.

It also seems that [Scalaz has some facility for HTTP](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/http/request/Method.scala.html), but I cannot find any documentation for it either.

Comment: http://databinder.net/dispatch-doc/

Comment: Thank you for the API. From that I may able to figure out how to actually use the library. Still, I would like to have something intermediate, like a high level description of the API. I imagine something along the lines of "To make a POST request, you use this constructor, with these parameters and so on".

Comment: Agreed that Dispatch could use better documentation. I think your best bet for now is to ask on the Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dispatch-scala

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I use the following: https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http.

Here's a simple GET request:

```
import scalaj.http.{Http, HttpOptions}

Http("http://example.com/search").param("q", "monkeys").asString
```

and an example of a POST:

```
val result = Http("http://example.com/url").postData("""{"id":"12","json":"data"}""")
  .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .header("Charset", "UTF-8")
  .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(10000)).asString
```

Scalaj HTTP is available through SBT:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-http_2.11" % "2.3.0"
```

Comment: I turns out to be the simplest option! I am still curious to learn about Dispatch and the reason of its peculiar syntax

Comment: Note: the default connection timeout is pretty low (100 millis), so if you are receiving a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`, then add a line such as `.option(HttpOptions.connTimeout(10000))`

Comment: It's not compatible with scala 2.11 anymore since they removed ScalaObject. Waiting eagerly for scalaj-http to update their library.

Comment: @Dalvik I think they've cleaned their game; just add `"org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "1.1.4"` to build.sbt.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone else has had trouble getting a response with "asParamsMap"  on post, but I ended up having to use "asString" and then parsing explicitly with net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser.

Comment: What's wrong with using `scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString`? I guess you can't use headers and some other options - but for a truly simple get request, what else do you need?

Comment: It's interesting how the execute is called from asString apart from other areas in that library

Comment: check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalaj/scalaj-http for the latest versions of scalaj http

Comment: You need to call the execute method of Http in order to make the actual connection and get a response, I have no idea why the author of this post didn't include that information...

Comment: can anyone tell me if there is any way to increase the response size like how we increase the timeout

Comment: Just heads up, The repository has been archived by the owner on Apr 4, 2022. It is now read-only. This is based on the message from https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http

Answer (score 7):

You could use [spray-client](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-client/).  The documentation is lacking (it took me some digging to find out [how to make GET requests with query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463387/scala-url-with-query-string-parser-and-builder-dsl)) but it's a great option if you are already using spray.  And the documentation is better than dispatch.

We're using it at [AI2](http://allenai.org/) over [dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) because the operators are less symbolic and we're already using spray/actors.

```
import spray.client.pipelining._

val url = "http://youruri.com/yo"
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive

// Post with header and parameters
val responseFuture1: Future[String] = pipeline(Post(Uri(url) withParams ("param" -> paramValue), yourPostData) map (_.entity.asString)

// Post with header
val responseFuture2: Future[String] = pipeline(Post(url, yourPostData)) map (_.entity.asString)
```

Comment: The main spray developer moved to akka, so even that spray is production ready, will be outdated, and AKKA-HTTP and  AKKA-STREAMS will be the next round for http clients and servers. 
http://akka.io/docs/

Answer (score 6):

Using my [Requests-Scala](https://github.com/lihaoyi/requests-scala) library:

```
// Mill
ivy"com.lihaoyi::requests:0.1.8"
// SBT
"com.lihaoyi" %% "requests" % "0.1.8"
```

This is as simple as

```
val r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/users/lihaoyi")

r.statusCode
// 200

r.headers("content-type")
// Buffer("application/json; charset=utf-8")

r.text
// {"login":"lihaoyi","id":934140,"node_id":"MDQ6VXNlcjkzNDE0MA==",...
```

```
val r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data = Map("key" -> "value"))

val r = requests.put("http://httpbin.org/put", data = Map("key" -> "value"))

val r = requests.delete("http://httpbin.org/delete")

val r = requests.head("http://httpbin.org/head")

val r = requests.options("http://httpbin.org/get")
```

Comment: Awesome Li,I also have some doubt, what about if I want to give Json to data in requests.post, do I have to extract the each key value pairs. Is there not a simple approach.

Comment: I got it, val json = """{"key":"value"}""".stripMargin
val r = requests.post(url,data=json)
val json = ujson.read(r.text())
println(json)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using dispatch: http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html

They've just released a new version (0.9.0) with a complete new api that I really like. And it is async.

Example from project page:

```
import dispatch._
val svc = url("http://api.hostip.info/country.php")
val country = Http(svc OK as.String)

for (c <- country)
  println(c)
```

edit: This might help you https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/requests.scala

Comment: Yes, I linked the project page. But I cannot find there how to make a simple POST request - or even a GET request with parameters and/or custom headers.

Comment: @Andrea - try this link: http://www.flotsam.nl/dispatch-periodic-table.html . It seems that `dispatch` author has some problems with main doc at the moment - just yesterday the docs were much better.

Comment: @Rogach isn't that just for the old dispatch?
Andrea: updated my post with a link to the sources

Comment: it can now:
`val svc = url("http://diasporafoundation.org/").POST.setBody("test")`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is Typesafe's play-ws, which is the Play Framework WS library broken out as a standalone lib:

http://blog.devalias.net/post/89810672067/play-framework-seperated-ws-library

I wouldn't necessarily offer this as the best option, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

If I can make a shameless plug, I have an API called [Bee-Client](https://bitbucket.org/rickb777/bee-client/overview) which is simply a wrapper in Scala for Java's HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any documentation available?

Comment: Yes but it's quite limited still. I'm working on some example usages. For now, have a look at the test code, especially the integration test https://bitbucket.org/rickb777/lighthttpclient/src/a6c526e4684b/src/test/scala/uk/co/bigbeeconsultants/http/HttpIntegration.scala

Comment: There is now some documentation on the wiki https://bitbucket.org/rickb777/lighthttpclient/wiki/Home

Comment: Good! But it seems to be private. I do not have my Bitbucket credentials right now. Probably you forgot to mark the wiki as public

Comment: Sorry for that. I moved the docs to my webserver instead:
http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/light-http-client
I've expanded the documentation too.

Comment: The documentation has since moved to http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client

Comment: please Rick add support for scala 2.11 or indicate in the doc than it's only available for scala <=2.10 ...I was pretty interested in use it but unfortunately seems than I can't because I'm stuck with scala 2.11 now....

Comment: Scala 2.11 support is almost ready for release. The remaining question is mostly whether to continue 2.9 support.

Comment: Version 0.28.0 supports Scala 2.11.

Comment: Upvoted strictly for *shameless plug*. Well done, sir.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same to test one end point (in Integration test). So following is the code to fetch response from GET request in Scala.
I am making use of scala.io.Source to read from endpoint and ObjectMapper for json to object conversion.

```
private def buildStockMasterUrl(url:String, stockStatus:Option[String]) = {
      stockStatus match  {
        case Some(stockStatus) => s"$url?stockStatus=${stockStatus}"
        case _ => url
    }
  }

    private def fetchBooksMasterData(stockStatus:Option[String]):  util.ArrayList[BooksMasterData] = {
    val url: String = buildBooksMasterUrl("http://localhost:8090/books/rest/catalogue/booksMasterData",stockStatus)
    val booksMasterJson : String = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    apper.readValue(booksMasterJson,classOf[util.ArrayList[BooksMasterData]])
}

case class BooksMasterData(id:String,description: String,category: String)
```

And here is my test method for the same

```
test("validate booksMasterData resource") {
    val booksMasterData = fetchBooksMasterData(Option(null))
    booksMasterData.size should be (740)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) ? Here's the [application FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/FrequentlyAskedApplicationDesignQuestions#GET_with_Query), which covers a wide range of scenarios.

Comment: I may use it, but I would be happier to learn a more idiomatic tool

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I was working on. It has both GET and POST requests. 
GET without parameters - POST with parameters
I used it to communicate with StreamSets in order to start a pipeline or check a pipeline status.

it only need the following dependency in the build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0"
```

You can find the documentation here: https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http#post-raw-arraybyte-or-string-data-and-get-response-code

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scalaj.http.{Http, HttpResponse}

object HttpRequestHandler {

  val userName: String = "admin"
  val password: String = "admin"

  def sendHttpGetRequest(request: String): String = {

    println(" Send Http Get Request (Start) ")

    try {

      val httpResponse: HttpResponse[String] = Http(request).auth(userName,password)
                                                            .asString

      val response = if (httpResponse.code == 200) httpResponse.body
      else{
        println("Bad HTTP response: code = "+httpResponse.code )
        return "ERROR"
      }

      println(" Send Http Get Request (End) ")

      return response

    } catch {
      case e: Exception => println("Error in sending Get request: "+e.getMessage)
        return "ERROR"
    }


  }

  def arrayBufferToJson(params:ArrayBuffer[(String,String)]): String ={

    var jsonString = "{"
    var count: Int = 0
    for(param <- params){
      jsonString+="\""+param._1+"\":\""+param._2+"\""+ ( if(count!=params.length-1) "," else "")
      count+=1
    }
    jsonString+="}"

    return jsonString

  }

  def sendHttpPostRequest(request: String,params: ArrayBuffer[(String,String)]): String = {

    println(" Send Http Post Request (Start) ")

    try {
      val postData : String = arrayBufferToJson(params)
      println("Parameters: "+postData)
      val httpResponse: HttpResponse[String] = Http(request).auth(userName,password)
                                                            .header("X-Requested-By","sdc")
                                                            .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                                                            .header("X-Stream" , "true")
                                                            .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                                            .postData(postData.getBytes)
                                                            .asString


      val response = if (httpResponse.code == 200) httpResponse.body
      else{
        println("Bad HTTP response: code = "+httpResponse.code )
        "ERROR"
      }

      println(" Send Http Post Request (End) ")

      return response

    } catch {
      case e: Exception => println("Error in sending Post request: " + e.getMessage)
        return "ERROR"
    }
  }

}
```