# Simple and concise HTTP client library for Scala

Tags: scala, http

I need a mature HTTP client library that is idiomatic to scala, concise in usage, simple semantics. I looked at the Apache HTTP and the Scala Dispatch and numerous new libraries that promise an idiomatic Scala wrapping. Apache HTTP client sure demands verbosity, while Dispatch was easily confusing.

What is a suitable HTTP client for Scala usage?

Comment: I'd suggest sticking with Dispatch. Sure, its operatoriness isn't to everyone's taste (it's not to mine), but it's not really as bad as it looks at first, and I'd guess that it's going to stay the most popular Scala option for a while.

Comment: This might be a bit off topic, but I think we should have a fork of dispatch with plain English method names. This would not be hard to do and maintain

Comment: @KimStebel Dispatch 0.9.x can be used with plain English methods alone.

Comment: A similar question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719373/doing-http-request-in-scala

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've recently started using [Dispatch](https://dispatchhttp.org/Dispatch.html), a bit arcane (great general intro, serious lack of detailed scenario/use-case based docs).  Dispatch 0.9.1 is a Scala wrapper around Ning's [Async Http Client](http://asynchttpclient.github.com/async-http-client/apidocs/overview-summary.html); to fully understand what going on requires introducing one's self to that library.  In practice, the only thing I really had to look at was the [RequestBuilder](http://asynchttpclient.github.com/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) - everything else falling nicely into my understanding of HTTP.

I give the 0.9 release a solid thumbs up (so far!) on getting the job done very simply.. once you get past that initial learning curve.

Dispatch's Http "builder" is immutable, and seems to work well in a threaded environment.  Though I can't find anything in docs to state that it is thread-safe; general reading of source suggests that it is.

Do be aware that the [RequestBuilder](http://asynchttpclient.github.com/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/RequestBuilder.html)'s are mutable, and therefore are NOT thread-safe.

Here are some additional links I've found helpful:

- I can't find a ScalaDoc link for the 0.9.* release, so I browse the [source code for the 0.9.* release](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot);
- [ScalaDoc for the 0.8 release](http://databinder.net/dispatch-doc/#dispatch.$colon$div$); a *substantially* different beast (today) than 0.9.
- [The "Periodic" Table](http://www.flotsam.nl/dispatch-periodic-table.html) of operators, also 0.8 related.
- The older [0.8 "dispatch-classic" docs](http://dispatch-classic.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) helped me understand how they used the url builders, and gave some hints on how things are tied together that did carry forward to 0.9.

Comment: Note that the periodic table of operators refer to the previous incarnation of Dispatch, and most of that has been cut off from 0.9.x, and probably won't come back.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  What little I've used has worked nicely: url builder shortcuts, POST, '<<'

Comment: Yes, the request DSL is there -- it's the response that was dumped, aside things like `as.String` and `as.xml.Elem`, which are not symbols.

Comment: Please help me with my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342062/basic-usage-of-dispatch-0-9

Comment: Why so many people recommend it? The DSL is hard to understand, the document is poor, the examples are few, I can't make a simplest working demo with it.

Comment: As the author of this response, I have to point out that it is dated.  2+ years later I'd start with akka-http, which a collaboration between the spray and akka teams: https://typesafe.com/blog/akka-http-preview.  I haven't actually *used* it yet, but that's where I would start.

Comment: And now a year later, I can say I've used _akka-http_ quite extensively.  It's got it's warts, but overall I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 29):

I did a [comparison of most major HTTP client libraries available](https://www.implicitdef.com/2015/11/19/comparing-scala-http-client-libraries.html)

Dispatch, and a few others libraries, **are not maintained anymore**.
The only serious ones currently are **spray-client** and **Play! WS**.

**spray-client** is a bit arcane in its syntax. **play-ws** is quite easy to use :

(build.sbt)

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.4.3"
```

(basic usage)

```
val wsClient = NingWSClient()
wsClient
  .url("http://wwww.something.com")
  .get()
  .map { wsResponse =>
    // read the response
}
```

Comment: Dispatch had a reboot: https://github.com/dispatch/reboot
So it is a viable candidate again. If you can get over the cryptic function 'names', it is a very pleasant library.

Comment: Doesn't Play WS depend on Akka?

Comment: _"spray-client is a bit arcane"_ - I dig arcane syntax personally, but it can result in some IDE glitches.  That said I've only ever run into one syntactical glitch with _IntelliJ IDEA_ and `spray-can` spec testing.

Answer (score 21):

A little late to the party here, but I've been impressed with [spray-client](https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/spray-client).

It's got a nice DSL for building requests, supports both sync and async execution, as well as a variety of (un)marshalling types (JSON, XML, forms). It plays very nicely with [Akka](http://akka.io/), too.

Comment: spray client unfortunately states that the chunked requests and responses are not supported. So how could you download or upload very large files in a system with limited memory? (i.e. android & scala)

Comment: Spray now depends on Akka.

Answer (score 15):

[sttp](https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp) is the Scala HTTP library we've all been waiting for!

It has a fluent DSL for forming and executing requests (code samples from their README):

```
val request = sttp
  .cookie("session", "*!@#!@!$")
  .body(file) // of type java.io.File
  .put(uri"http://httpbin.org/put")
  .auth.basic("me", "1234")
  .header("Custom-Header", "Custom-Value")
  .response(asByteArray)
```

It supports synchronous, asynchronous, and streaming calls via pluggable backends, including Akka-HTTP (formerly Spray) and the venerable AsyncHttpClient (Netty):

```
implicit val sttpHandler = AsyncHttpClientFutureHandler()
val futureFirstResponse: Future[Response[String]] = request.send()
```

It supports `scala.concurrent.Future`, `scalaz.concurrent.Task`, `monix.eval.Task`, and `cats.effect.IO` - all the major Scala IO monad libraries.

Plus it has a few additional tricks up its sleeve:

- It has case class representations for both requests and responses (although it doesn't go as far as having e.g. strongly typed headers):
  https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/softwaremill/sttp/RequestT.scala
  https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/softwaremill/sttp/Response.scala
- It provides a [URI string interpolator](https://softwaremill.com/sttp-streaming-uri-interpolator/):

`val test = "chrabąszcz majowy"
val testUri: Uri = uri"http://httpbin.org/get?bug=$test"`

- It supports encoders/decoders for request bodies/responses e.g. JSON via Circe:

`import com.softwaremill.sttp.circe._
val response: Either[io.circe.Error, Response] = 
  sttp
    .post(uri"...")
    .body(requestPayload)
     .response(asJson[Response])
     .send()`

Finally, it's maintained by the reliable folks at softwaremill and it's got great [documentation](https://softwaremill.com/introducing-sttp-the-scala-http-client).

Answer (score 14):

<strike>Two</strike> Six years after originally responding to this post, I would have a different answer.

I've been using [akka-http](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/index.html?language=scala), a collaboration between the spray and akka teams.  It's backed by Lightbend, tightly aligned with the akka async environment... it's the right tool for this job.

Comment: Sadly, today Client Api documentation is still empty
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/http/client.html

Comment: here's the official client side doc for akka-http: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.11/scala/http/client-side/index.html

Comment: the akka-http client is provided as part of the akka-http-core library. the experimental link provided by @WaldemarWosiński was an initial prototype project for what became the official client in akka-http. Because of that you'll want to use the akka-http link and not the earlier link to the orphaned "experimental" project.

Comment: This article comparing a few solutions comes from November 2015: https://www.implicitdef.com/2015/11/19/comparing-scala-http-client-libraries.html

Answer (score 10):

Having had some unhappy experiences with the Apache client, I set about writing my own. The built-in HttpURLConnection is widely asserted to be buggy. But that's not my experience of it. In fact, the reverse has been so, the Apache client having a somewhat problematic threading model. Since Java6 (or 5?), HttpURLConnection has provided efficient HTTP1.1 connections with essentials like keep-alive being built in, and it handles concurrent usage without fuss.

So, to compensate for the inconvenient API offered by HttpURLConnection, I set about writing a new API in Scala, as an open-source project. It's just a wrapper for HttpURLConnection, but unlike HttpURLConnection, it aims to be easy to use. Unlike Apache client, it should fit easily into an existing project. Unlike Dispatch, it should be easy to learn.

It's called Bee Client

- Website: http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client
- API docs: http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/docs/bee-client/latest.html

My apologies for the shameless plug. :)

Comment: I'm trying to add it as Maven dependency, no luck. Maybe I must add another repository first?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you been able to use keep-alive with `HttpUrlConnection` on a per-connection basis, or is there really no other way than the global system property?

Comment: The `Config` object has a `keepAlive` boolean: it controls whether the connections are to be closed or kept-alive on a per-connection basis (http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/docs/bee-client/latest/#uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http.Config$).

Comment: Is this lib still maintained? The link to the source repo is bust and there doesn't seem to be a build for any versions of scala later than 2.11.

Answer (score 5):

Besides Dispatch there is not much out there. [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/master/http) had a attempt at building a functional http client. But it is outdated for a while an no version of it exists in the scalaz7 branch. Additionally there is a useful [wrapper](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala) of the ning async-http-client within the playframework. There your can do calls like:

```
WS.url("http://example.com/feed").get()
WS.url("http://example.com/item").post("content")
```

You can use this API as inspiration if you don't use play! in your project and dislike the Dispatch API.

Answer (score 4):

**Spray**

You really should consider using [Spray](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-client/). In my opinion it has a bit of tricky syntax, but it is still pretty usable if you aim to build a high-performance http client. The main advantage of using Spray is that it is based on the [akka](http://akka.io/) actor library, which is extremely scalable and powerful. You can scale out your http client to several machines by only changing `conf` files.

*Moreover few month ago Spray join Typesafe, and as I understand it will become a part of the basic akka distribution. [proof](http://www.typesafe.com/blog/typesafe-gets-sprayed)*

**Play2**

Another option is the Play2 WS lib usage ([doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS)). As far as I know it is still not separated from the Play distribution, but due to its extremely simplicity it is worth it to spend some time attaching the whole Play framework to get that part. There are some issues with providing configuration to it, so this is not great for drop-and-use cases. However, we have used it in few non Play-based projects and everything was fine.

Answer (score 3):

ScalaJ-Http is a very simple synchronous http client

https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http

I'd recommend it if you need a no-ceremony barebones Scala client.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised that no one mentioned finagle here. It is super simple to use:

```
import com.twitter.finagle.{Http, Service}
import com.twitter.finagle.http
import com.twitter.util.{Await, Future}

object Client extends App {
  val client: Service[http.Request, http.Response] = Http.newService("www.scala-lang.org:80")
  val request = http.Request(http.Method.Get, "/")
  request.host = "www.scala-lang.org"
  val response: Future[http.Response] = client(request)
  Await.result(response.onSuccess { rep: http.Response =>
    println("GET success: " + rep)
  })
}
```

See quick start guid for more detail: https://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/Quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

I've used Dispatch, Spray Client and the Play WS Client Library...None of them were simply to use or configure. So I created a simpler HTTP Client library which lets you perform all the classic HTTP requests in simple one-liners.

See an example:

```
import cirrus.clients.BasicHTTP.GET

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object MinimalExample extends App {

  val html = Await.result(Cirrus(GET("https://www.google.co.uk")), 3 seconds)

  println(html)
}
```

... produces ...

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-GB">...</html>
```

The library is called Cirrus and is available via Maven Central

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.godis" % "cirrus_2.11" % "1.4.1"
```

The documentation is available on GitHub

```
https://github.com/Godis/Cirrus
```