# Simple use of dispatch

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scala-dispatch

I'm about to set up a stupid play/scala app whose only job will be to make some http call once it receives calls itself

```
GET /abracadabra controllers.Application.abracadabra(stuff: String)
```

and then

```
      def abracadabra(stuff: String) = Action {
        Logger.info("called for stuff: "+stuff);
            // call this other URL with 'stuff' as get parameter
            // log http return status code and return Ok/200 anyways
      }
```

Now for the second (commented) part I thought about using [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net).

I've read the docs but I can't just figure out how to use Promises and all that.

If anybody could point me to some sample code or something, it will be much appreciated

Comment: I give a basic Dispatch 0.9 example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12343111/334519). If you're using Play, though, you may be better off with the [WS library](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaWS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Play! has a built in Async library, you should probably go ahead and use that unless there's a feature in Dispatch that you specifically need.

Here's a short example:

```
def abracadabra(stuff: String) = Action {
  Logger.info("called for stuff: "+stuff);
  Async {
    WS.url("http://stackoverflow.com/").get().map { response =>
      Ok("I got it: " + response)
    }
  }  
}
```

The documentation is here: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaWS

Comment: Thanks @Travis Brown and andrew. You both were helpful. I'm new to scalaDoc and play, so I'm figuring out how to handle option http method too.