# Dispatch error handling

Tags: scala, playframework

I get my response from my requests this (simple, blocking) way:

```
val response = Http(req)()
```

But I got this error from Play! framework:

```
ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused to http://localhost:8983/update/json?commit=true&wt=json
```

---

I have never thought about exception handling in Dispatch or Scala for that matter. What are the errors i must watch for in Dispatch library? What is the statement to catch each type/ class of errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One common way of handling exceptions in this kind of situation, where failure of some kind isn't actually that exceptional, is to use `Either[Throwable, Whatever]` to represent the result. Dispatch 0.9 makes this convenient with the `either` method on `Promise` (which I use in [my answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12343111/334519), by the way):

```
import com.ning.http.client.Response

val response: Either[Throwable, Response] = Http(req).either()
```

Now you can very naturally use pattern matching to handle exceptions:

```
import java.net.ConnectException

response match {
  case Right(res)                => println(res.getResponseBody)
  case Left(_: ConnectException) => println("Can't connect!")
  case Left(StatusCode(404))     => println("Not found!")
  case Left(StatusCode(code))    => println("Some other code: " + code.toString)
  case Left(e)                   => println("Something else: " + e.getMessage)
}
```

There are also many other ways that you can use `Either` to make handling failures more convenient—see for example [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1194541/334519).

Comment: Is there a way to get the response body, when other than 200 HTTP code is returned?

Comment: Hi, does the pattern match there wait or block until you get a response, like if you use a for comprehension? I'm a bit confused about if its safe to use this solution. Thanks!