# What to do when website not responding with HTTP error code?

Tags: scala, http

I am trying to connect to a website ABC.com ( HTTP API endpoint). However , due to some problem in the website's end I am not getting a response.

```
  val httpclient: CloseableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom()
  .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
  .build()
  val getSlowQueryRequest: HttpGet = new HttpGet(mySQLHost + "cgi-bin/" + slowQueryLink)
  val slowQueryResponse: CloseableHttpResponse = httpclient.execute(getSlowQueryRequest)
```

The program gets stuck after httpclient.execute() . I tried manually opening the website and even then it was not giving any response. 
Because of this , the rest of the program gets hung up! Is there some way I can set up some timer to wait for sometime and in case I do not get a response , move on after skipping the test?

EDIT:

Also could it be because of using SSL? Does CloseableHttpClient not provide any default timeout value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val requestConfig: RequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
      .setSocketTimeout(30 * 1000) //30 sec timeout
      .setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000)
      .build()
    val sslsf: SSLConnectionSocketFactory = Utility.getTrustAllSSLFactory
    val httpclient: CloseableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom()
      .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
      .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
      .build()
```

This works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpAsyncClient for your request

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/quickstart.html

So your call will be:

```
 val futureResponse: Future<HttpResponse> = httpclient.execute(request1, null);
```

And you can make further processing using onComplete for a Future.

Another option is to use some Scala native library, like
http://dispatch.databinder.net/Bargaining+with+futures.html

```
import dispatch._, Defaults._
val svc = url("http://api.hostip.info/country.php")
val country = Http(svc OK as.String)
val length = for (c <- country) yield c.length
```

The length value is a future of integer.

Basically, Scala suggests nonblocking processing, as soon as you start waiting here and there , you loose all the benefits.

Here is some similar question, which can give you more clues

[Simple and concise HTTP client library for Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334476/simple-and-concise-http-client-library-for-scala)

Comment: Isn't there a more direct method which CloseableHttpClient provides to set a timeout without involving Future as I am not very familiar with the concept ?

Comment: I think, there is a default timeout in CloseableHttpRequest, but you saw what it does to your system. You will have smaller outages, woth smaller timeouts, but problem will remain.