# SocketTimeoutException when I use Scalaj request

Tags: json, scala, httprequest, spray

I'm trying to make a simple https request using this library https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http . The request contains some json data.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
  val jsonHeaders = """{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "someMethod", "params": {"dataIds":["12348" , "456"]}, "data2": "777"}"""

  val result = Http.postData("https://someurl.com/json-rpc", jsonHeaders)
    .header("content-type", "application/json")
    .header("X-Application", "myCode")
    .header("X-Authentication", "myCode2")
    .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(10000))
    .asString
    //.responseCode -- the same error

  println(result)
```

And it always returns me a timeout error:

```
[error] (run-main) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at scalaj.http.Http$$anonfun$3.apply(Http.scala:263)
    at scalaj.http.Http$$anonfun$3.apply(Http.scala:261)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.process(Http.scala:102)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.apply(Http.scala:90)
    at scalaj.http.Http$Request.asString(Http.scala:133)
    at Application$delayedInit$body.apply(Application.scala:27)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at Application$.main(Application.scala:8)
    at Application.main(Application.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

If I do just

```
val jsonHeaders = """{"version123": "12.0", "method": "someMethod", "params": {"dataIds": ["12348" , "456"]}, "data2": "777"}"""
val result = Http.postData("https://someurl.com/some-url2", jsonHeaders)
        .header("content-type", "application/json")
        .header("X-Application", "myCode")
        .header("X-Application1234", "myCode2")
        .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(10000))
println(result)
```

it returns

```
Request(POST,<function2>,<function1>,List(),List((X-Authentication,myCode2), (X-Application1234,myCode), (content-type,application/json)),List(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>),DIRECT)
```

What do I do wrong and is there any another simple way to send https request? Even if involves `spray` framework, it would be ok (I don't find any example of how to do that in `spray`, though).

**UPDATE**:

An example has been taken from here [Doing HTTP request in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719373/doing-http-request-in-scala)

Comment: Looks like your second request doesn't do any actual request -- it just constructs request object, which then get triggered by `asString`. Are you sure that request can be fulfilled within the specified timeout (e.g. have you tried to do the same with curl).

Comment: @om-nom-nom I can comment out the timeout and nothing will be changed at all.

Comment: @om-nom-nom look at my update. I can also do this request in Python and it will work well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to specify a connection timeout alongside your current read timeout with: `.option(HttpOptions.connTimeout(10000)).option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(50000))`. Change the `10000` to a value that works for you. The default connection timeout is a pretty aggressive `100`.

You do already have a read timeout specified, but the exception says it is timing out on establishing the connection, not on the the reading of the response.

See docs: https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http#custom-connect-and-read-timeouts

Comment: it didn't help. Even if I increase 60000 10 times, it seems like it turns a blind eye to it -- there is no difference at all, meaning it exists with the error so fast as before.

Comment: maybe I confused the arguments' order?

Comment: Weird. Just to check: you are specifying both a `HttpOptions.readTimeout` and a `HttpOptions.connTimeout`? I don't think the order should make any difference. Here is an example of how I have been using both: https://github.com/theon/xsbt-coveralls-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/theon/coveralls/CoverallsClient.scala#L48 .

Comment: It seems to work now, it returns the empty result, though. but it does return it.

Answer (score 0):

On the `HttpRequest` object there is also a `.timeout()` member method. This method is defined as:

```
  /** The socket connection and read timeouts in milliseconds. Defaults are 1000 and 5000 respectively */
  def timeout(connTimeoutMs: Int, readTimeoutMs: Int): HttpRequest = options(
    Seq(HttpOptions.connTimeout(connTimeoutMs), HttpOptions.readTimeout(readTimeoutMs))
  )
```

The nice part about this is that it was a bit easier to mock using `Mockito`. See [github](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http/blob/aa239da0e218ba110b2504b07520b742e01b27ab/src/main/scala/scalaj/http/Http.scala#L331) as the reference.